# Getting arg to work in a varag function in Lua 5.2 (integrated in Delphi)

Tags: delphi, lua

When using the Lua 5.2 API, the code below prints "nil"

```
function __debug(szName, ...)
    print(type(arg));
end

__debug("s", 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

But this code does work when using Lua 5.1, and prints "table"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are referring to vararg function, the `arg` table [was deprecated already in Lua 5.1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#7.1). In Lua 5.2, you can use [`table.pack`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-table.pack) to create `arg` if you need it:

```
function debug(name, ...)
    local arg = table.pack(...)
    print(name)
    for i=1,arg.n do
        print(i, arg[i])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because `arg` has been deprecated since Lua 5.1. It only remained as a compatibility feature.

References: [Lua 5.1 manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#7.1), [unofficial LuaFaq](http://www.luafaq.org/#T8.1.1)

a workaround is using this line to generate a table called arg:

```
local arg={...}
```