# Using Lua from the Command Line With ... for Function

Tags: command-line, lua, command-line-arguments

I've used Lua with Corona SDK for a long time, but I only just downloaded the standalone Lua interpreter (invoked from the command line). When I use

```
lua main.lua
```

From the Mac terminal, for some reason, any functions that use `(...)` no longer have access to `arg` as their `...` arguments; rather, `arg` now points to the command line arguments.

My question: is there a way to invoke Lua from the command line and still have functions like

```
local function myFunction(...)
  print(arg[1])
end
```

With them pointing to the their own `...` arguments, not the command line ones?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting arg to work in a varag function in Lua 5.2 (integrated in Delphi)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786051/getting-arg-to-work-in-a-varag-function-in-lua-5-2-integrated-in-delphi)

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that Corona is still Lua 5.1 based. I don't know if they feel any pressure to change, especially given that LuaJIT is still primarily 5.1 with just a few tweaks from 5.2 optionally available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>What about saving those command line arguments on some variable or table just at the entry point? Example:</strike>

```
local function myFunction(...)
    print(cmd_arg)
end
-- Entry point:
local cmd_arg = arg[1]
myFunction()
```

or collecting all of command line arguments into table:

```
local function myFunction(...)
    print(cmd_arg[1])
end

-- Entry point:
local cmd_args = {}
for _, cmd_arg in arg do
    table.insert(cmd_args, cmd_arg)
end
myFunction()
```

EDIT: the solution is already mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9787126/1150918

`arg` appears to be deprecated since 5.1.

And [Michal Kottman's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221509/michal-kottman) solution was:

```
function debug(name, ...)
    local arg = table.pack(...)
    print(name)
    for i=1,arg.n do
        print(i, arg[i])
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer - the above is what I *don't* want. I want each function to have `arg` point to its personal `...` arguments, **not** the command line ones

Comment: @CalebP, oh, no, sorry. It's just deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786051/getting-arg-to-work-in-a-varag-function-in-lua-5-2-integrated-in-delphi

Comment: I must point out that calling a function `debug` is generally a bad idea in Lua, since it's [the name of one of the standard libraries](http://www.lua.org/pil/23.html).